# How to use CSV.open and CSV.foreach methods to convert specific data in a csv file?

Tags: ruby, csv

The `Old.csv` file contains these headers, `"article_category_id", "articleID", "timestamp", "udid"`, but some of the values in those columns are strings. So, I am trying to convert them to integers and store in another CSV file, `New.csv`. This is my code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'time'

CSV.foreach('New.csv', "wb", :write_headers=> true, :headers =>["article_category_id", "articleID", "timestamp", "udid"]) do |csv|
    CSV.open('Old.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|

        csv['article_category_id']=row['article_category_id'].to_i
        csv['articleID']=row['articleID'].to_i
        csv['timestamp'] = row['timestamp'].to_time.to_i unless row['timestamp'].nil?

        unless udids.include?(row['udid'])
          udids << row['udid']
        end
        csv['udid'] = udids.index(row['udid']) + 1

        csv<<row
    end
end
```

But, I am getting the following error: `in 'foreach': ruby wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)`.

When I change the `foreach` to `open`, I get the following error: `undefined method '[]' for #<CSV:0x36e0298> (NoMethodError)`. Why is that? And how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full error message, so that we can super quickly identify where the error comes from, thanks,

Comment: That is the full error message. But if you insist, I am copy pasting the whole thing from the command line here: `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1119:in 'foreach': wrong number of arguments (3
for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/ex.rb:10:in '<main>'`

Comment: Note that `CSV` has built-in [converters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) for various types, including `:integer`

Comment: You want to READ from `Old.csv` and write to `New.csv`? Please read the Docs. From `#foreach`s doc: "This method is intended as the primary interface for **reading** CSV files." http://devdocs.io/ruby/csv#method-c-foreach

Answer (score 4):

[`CSV#foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) does not accept file access rights as second parameter:

```
CSV.open('New.csv', :headers=>true) do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('Old.csv',
    :write_headers => true, 
    :headers => ["article_category_id", "articleID", "timestamp", "udid"]
  ) do |row|
    row['article_category_id'] = row['article_category_id'].to_i
    ...
    csv << row
  end
end
```

`CSV#open` should be placed before `foreach`. You are to iterate the *old one* and produce the *new one*. Inside the loop you should change `row` and than append it to the output.

Comment: No, but how will it copy into `New.csv` now from `Old.csv`?

Comment: With that, I get the following error: `undefined method '[]' for #<CSV:0x36e0298> (NoMethodError)`.

And by the way, the headers need to be written for `New. csv`, not for `Old.csv`. `Old.csv` already has the headers.

Comment: Today is not my day. Please see an update, now it must work as expected.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now it is not throwing any error. However, it is strange now because it is copying everything as it is into the new one; it did not do any conversion at all. I removed the lines of code inside the 2 loops just to see what happens; it still copies all the columns as it is from the old to the new one. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'time'

CSV.open('New.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["article_category_id", "articleID", "timestamp", "udid"]
  CSV.foreach('Old.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
    array = []
    article_category_id=row['article_category_id'].to_i
    articleID=row['articleID'].to_i
    timestamp = row['timestamp'].to_i unless row['timestamp'].nil?

    unless udids.include?(row['udid'])
      udids << row['udid']
    end
    udid = udids.index(row['udid']) + 1
    array << [article_category_id, articleID, timestamp, udid]

    csv<<array
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I tried. But my whole file contains just this:
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
`"[0, 0, nil, 1]"`
And they come with those double quotes. All identical rows of wrong numbers. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Vinh answer is that at the end array variable is an array which has array inside.
So what is inserted indo CVS looks like
    [[article_category_id, articleID, timestamp, udid]]
And that is why you get results in double quotes.

Please try something like this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'time'

CSV.open('New.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["article_category_id", "articleID", "timestamp", "udid"]
  CSV.foreach('Old.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
    article_category_id = row['article_category_id'].to_i
    articleID = row['articleID'].to_i
    timestamp = row['timestamp'].to_i unless row['timestamp'].nil?

    unless udids.include?(row['udid'])
      udids << row['udid']
    end
    udid = udids.index(row['udid']) + 1
    output_row = [article_category_id, articleID, timestamp, udid]

    csv << output_row
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! I see now. Thanks a lot.